# How to replace static driver method

Tags: java, selenium

```
public class CommonFunctions {

  public static WebDriver driver;

  public void openWebsite(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
  }

  public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.close();
  }
}
```

```
public class TestCase {

  CommonFunctions commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();

  @BeforeMethod
  public void openWeb() {
    homePage.openWeb();
  }

  @Test
  public void navigateLoginPage() {
    homePage.login();
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void closeBrowser() {
    commonFunctions.closeBrowser();
  }
}
```

I have two class (commonfunction,homepage and testcase). When I run code without "**static**" at "**public static Webdriver driver**", the code throw nullpointerexception at function "**closeBrowser**". How to fix this error. I don't want use method "**public static Webdriver driver**" as code.

Comment: Please make the effort to format your code properly. Make it easy for the people, who will help you with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `driver` variable in your `CommonFunctions` class.

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(... etc);
```

Or, write a constructor that initializes this variable.

```
public class CommonFunctions 
{
  public WebDriver driver;

  public CommonFunctions() // Constructor
  {
      driver = new WebDriver();
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie. Can you explain more? I still don't understand about it.

Comment: The `driver` variable is null unless you assign something to it.  See my updated answer.